# How to write more than one object result to one output text file in Java?

Tags: java

I have more than one objects with different output, and I want to print all results in one text file, with each object's result on one line without overwriting any values.

I have written the following code; however, the output text file only saves the values of the last object (Object2).  I want the output file save the result as following:

```
Q = 1    
Q = 2
```

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Output {
    public static int Q;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object1();
        Object2();
    }

    public static void Object1() {
        Q = 1;
        Print();
    }

    public static void Object2() {
        Q = 2;
        Print();
    }

    public static void Print() {
        PrintWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\My Document\\Desktop\\Out.txt");
            if (Q == 1) {
                writer.println("Q =" + 1);
            }
            if (Q == 2) {
                writer.println("Q = " + 2);
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a [`FileWriter(File file, boolean append)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean)).  You can wrap it in a `BufferedWriter` and get `newLine` support. Also, have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for better ideas about how to manage your resources

Comment: Is there a reason you're only writing things for Q=1 or Q=2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your `Out.txt` file with the new information. You need to **append** your data.

Replace your line with this:

```
writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\My Document\\Desktop\\Out.txt", true)));
```

Comment: How can I append the data?

Answer (score 2):

A `FileWriter` is the right way to go about this.  You don't need to wrap it in anything, either.

Specifying `true` in the constructor enables the append mode (so be careful on subsequent runs).  Since Q can't be both 1 and 2, we write a new line after we're done with the block.

Since this is a try-with-resources statement, you don't need to worry about closing out the resource when you're done, as that is taken care of for you.

```
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("test.txt", true)) {
    if (Q == 1) {
        writer.write("Q =" + 1);
    }
    if (Q == 2) {
        writer.write("Q = " + 2);
    }
    writer.write("\n");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```